# I am writing a project with flask (for python) and when I run from the Visual Studio Code 2. The project included html files I got this error message;

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'index'[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdwXW.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIerN.png)

This was the code block from where I encountered the challenge

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbar"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="login" href="/login">Login</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="signUp" href="/sign-up">Sign Up</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="logout" href="/logout">Logout</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="home" href="/">Home</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{{ url_for('static, filename='index.js') }}"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

PLEASE I WILL APPRECIATE SOME INSIGHTS AS TO WHAT I WAS DOING WRONG

Comment: Within the `url_for` call, the string `static` is not closed by a `'`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the attached screenshot, you didn't correctly terminate arguments of `url_for()`.

In your code, it looks like this:

```
src="{{ url_for('static, filename='index.js') }}"
```

while it should look like this (second `'` after `static`):

```
src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"
```